# I am getting the following error Couldn't find Post with 'id'= and can't find a way around it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

I am getting Couldn't find Post with 'id'= over and over again. I am trying to render Posts that were created by the signed in user to their profile page.

Here is my entire User_controller,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
after_action :signed_in_after_register, only: :create 


def index
 @users = User.all

end

def profile 
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
  redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end 

def destroy
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
end

def welcome
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @posts = @user.posts
end

def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to profile_path, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
      end
    end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully  updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully   destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
        def set_user
          @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
    def signed_in_after_register 
      session[:user_id] = @user.id 

    end
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation,  :email, :age, :profile_picture, :post)
  end
end
```

I also have the following in my Posts_controller,

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end
    def new 
        @post = Post.new
    end
    def create 
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

      if @post.save 
          redirect_to @post 
      else
          render 'new'
     end
end
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

end
def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:body))
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
end

    private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:body)
   end
end
```

And the following is in my routes file,

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'welcome#welcome'

  get 'login' => 'sessions#login', :as => :login 

  get 'profile' => 'users#profile', :as => :profile

  post 'logging/user' => 'sessions#create'  

  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout 

  get 'about' => 'about'

  resources :users

  resources  :posts

  get 'index' => 'posts#index'

  get 'register' => 'users#new', :as => :register
```

This is in my posts model,

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :body, presence: true
end
```

and this is in my users model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true 
  validates_inclusion_of :age, in: 10..100
  validates :password, presence: true 
  has_many :posts
  has_attached_file :profile_picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>",  :thumb => "300x200>" }, 
  :default_url => "app/assets/images/missing.png", 
  :path =>  ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename" 
  validates_attachment_content_type :profile_picture, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

If you could give me some advice on this it'd be very helpful! I've been stuck on this little problem for days!

Comment: Please post the `error stacktrace`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't render user posts in the profile page: you have

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

in the `profile` action of your controller.

And you clearly don't have a post id param in your route.

Just replace this line by

```
@posts = @user.posts
```

like you do in the `show` action.

Also, I'm not sure you really need this custom `profile` action if you render the exact same thing in the `show`.

Comment: I followed this and did what you said but got this error now, SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: posts.user_id: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = ?

Comment: This is because you didn't add user_id in your `posts` table. You can add it by running this migration: `rails g migration add_user_id_to_posts user_id:integer` and then `rake db:migrate`. Check the guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Well so far you have been very helpful, I have just one problem now. I am getting this returned from my post [] Just the two brackets. This is what I'm using to get the post <%= @posts.each do |post| %>
       <div class="post_wrapper">
        <h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.body, post %></h2>
        <p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %> </p>
       </div>
      <% end %>

Comment: Your code looks ok but it seems that the posts don't belong to your user. You should permit user_id in your posts controller and this could be a good idea to have something like `@user.posts.create(post_params)` in the create action after retrieving the current user. And still, everything is in the guide ;)

Comment: I've been following that guide and still having more issues with it. Talking to actual people helps me because they've been through almost every error that their could be. Like now, I did what you said. Also followed the guides suggestions and no error but it doesn't work overall.

Comment: Right now, user_id must be nil for every post. Take a look in your console with `Post.map(&:user_id)`. This is why @posts is always empty since it is set to contain posts for a given user. Update this attribute with something like: `Post.first.update_attributes(user_id: 1)` and then visit /users/1. You should see the first post here.

Comment: Okay, Its showing the posts from just user one. In this case it works, How can I set it for all users?

Comment: Like I told you in a previous comment, you have to change the `create` action of you posts controller so that the user_id is automatically set when a post is created.